# How to send message to mute sound through activities

Tags: volume, mute

As the title, I want to mute sound when hitting X button or unmute when hitting Y button, and I want to keep this status through activities. Here is my code.

When hitting X button:

```
mSound.setVolume(0, 0);
sound = "SOUND_OFF";
```

Y button:

```
mSound.setVolume(1, 1);
sound = "SOUND_ON"
```

**When I finish my first activity:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.englishtest.Question.class);
                                        i.putExtra("checkSound", sound);
                                        startActivity(i);
                                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
                                        finish();
```

**In my second activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null) {
        sound = extras.getString("checkSound");
        checkVolume(sound);
    }
```

My checkVolume function:

```
    public void checkVolume(String s){
    if(s=="SOUND_ON"){
        mSound.setVolume(1, 1);
    }
    else if(s=="SOUND_OFF"){
        mSound.setVolume(0, 0);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone show me my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Too late from the moment you post this question. But I think your approaching is bad.
Let create another class with a static field to hold configuration status.
Such as:

```
public class Configuration {
    public static boolean soundOn;
}
```

Initialize this field in the main Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedBundle) {
    Configuration.soundOn = true;
    ...
}
```

Then just checking this field whenever you wanna setVolume and remember to save new status to this field when setting mute/unmute from any activity.

Comment: A yes, I figured it out 4 or 5 month ago =) btw, thank you for your reply, my approach is nearly similar to yours ;)